# Button Down Event in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I wanna use a button (not a key) just like backspace so when it is down do something repeatedly.
I've found proper code for hardware keys but as I mentioned I want a BUTTON do such things.
Thanks

Comment: You will need to respond to touch events rather than the higher level `onClick()` event usually used with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Scott. Finally I found the answer and did the job.

```
public MyActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 

private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable() 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        Log.i("repeatBtn", "repeat click"); 
        mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100); 
    } 
}; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    Button repeatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.repeatButton); 
    repeatButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    { 
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) 
        { 
            int action = motionevent.getAction(); 
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            { 
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN"); 
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask); 
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100); 
            } 
            else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            { 
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP"); 
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask); 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an `OnTouchListener` on a Button instance. You can then override the `onTouch` method of the of the listener to do what it is that you want until MotionEvent passed to the `onTouch` method has `MotionEvent.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. See this link for an example:

[Android onTouch Listener event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356283/android-ontouch-listener-event)

A switch statement is sufficient, just customize it to fit your needs using what I said above. --hope this helps, Scott

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer.But I can't do something repeatedly.It occurs just once and I failed to use a loop that do this until key is up

Comment: @user2548538 I assume that you have a either a switch or an if else in `onTouch()`. If you want the event to continue happening, make sure that you return false from the portion of your code (either the case statement or the if/else portion). Only return true from `onTouch()` when MotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP (this is called consuming the motion event). -- hope this helps